# Android tableview with dynamic numbers columns and rows

Tags: java, android, xml, tableview

This is actually a memory training app, with matrix of squares wich flips to their other side and than back to first side. And user need to click on squares that flipped. You know what I mean?
[image]

Something like that.

What I need is that sizes of the matrix would change dynamically. If user have been passed one level of complexity (matrix size is 4x4 for example), then matrix size would grow (5x5 for example), and if not then matrix size would get smaller (3x3 for example). I hope that's clear, and if not - sorry, English is not my native language =)

So if I would do it from code this would not be a problem. I would use ViewFlipper with some transition animation and create TableView with sizes that I want with inflater or something like that (or directly from code without using xml at all). And then adding it to ViewFlipper from code.

But somehow I don't like that idea.

Then next idea come into my mind. To do ViewFlipper with all possible tableviews in it and then just showNext(); or showPrevious(); depending on what user have done. But in this case XML would be of very great size.

So maybe someone knows the another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you to look [view-pager-example](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/),

using viewflipper showNext(); or showPrevious(); you had to download all data at the same time, but using fragmen, you can load only specific data assoiated with fragment.

you can change the view on every fragment like below

```
 @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new DetailFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            case 2:
                return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.thumb);

            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
```

[EDIT - For checking view in listener]

public class LoginExampleImplements extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn4.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v==btn1) {

    } else if(v==btn2) {

    } else if(v==btn3) {

    }  else if(v==btn4) {

    }
}
```

}

[EDIT 2]

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        LinearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            button.setId(i);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            LinearLayout1.addView(button);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button b = (Button)v;
        b.getId()
        // check clikedId   
    }
```

[EDIT 3]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{  
    ImageView img;
    LinearLayout LinearLayout1;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ln1);
         layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            img.setId(i);
            img.setTag(i);           
            layoutParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
            img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);          
            img.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            img.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            img.setOnClickListener(this);

            LinearLayout1.addView(img);            
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageView b = (ImageView)v;     
        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        b.setImageLevel(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(b.getTag())));
    }

}
```

Comment: How is that any different from what I said? =)
In this example it is just fragment used instead of ViewFlipper.
But I think inflate tables from xml is the right way to do it any way.
Thanks.

Comment: But I have another question. If I use one onClick method for many buttons, how can I differentiante the buttons?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't posting all my comment accidentaly.
In my case I have dymanic number of button and a lot of them. So switch case would be with about 100 cases. I think that is not good. I think I can probably check what button was clicked in a loop

for (int i = butto[1]ID; i < numberOfButtons; i++) something like that
if (i = v.getId())
button[i].setImageLevel(1);

where button[] - is array of buttons.

But it's to look stange to me. Maybe there is a more simple way. What I need is to know button number (all button is xml looks like "button1", "button2" etc

I need to know this "buttonx" x.

Comment: public void onImageClick (View v) {
  int id = v.getId();
  switch (id) {
   case R.id.imageView0:
    im[0].setImageLevel(1);
    flipper[0].showNext(); break;

That's my code. Problem is - I don't like switch case operator here. Because there would be about 100 cases. I have array of ImageView (with onclick listeners) And to every ImageView corresponds ViewFlipper. I need to know imageView*** exactly this *** number.

Comment: ok, look at edit 3. You can do what ever you want after catched the ide of your image. And you can carry a value by using setTag and getTag. I hope it helps

Comment: setTag and getTag would probably really help. Thanks a lot! :)